# TypeError: _stream.Readable.from is not a function in sequelize node js

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, sequelize.js, tedious

I am getting the below error when I am trying to establish a database connection in my node js application using sequelize

```
C:\Users\user123\Desktop\project\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:24
    this.parser = _stream.Readable.from(_streamParser.default.parseTokens(message, this.debug, this.options));
                                   ^

TypeError: _stream.Readable.from is not a function
```

I am in initial stage of creating an application. Where I have just tried to create a database connection, for which I have created three files

***index.js***

```
var dotenv = require("dotenv").config().parsed;
var customEnv = require("custom-env");
customEnv.env("development").env();


var express = require("express");
const helmet = require("helmet");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const app = express();

app.use(helmet());
app.use(cookieParser());
require("./db.js");


httpserver = require("http").createServer(app);
httpserver.timeout = 0;

httpserver.listen(3457, async () => {
   connectedEmitter.on("connectedDbs", () => {
    console.log(` ----- SERVER LISTENING ON PORT `);
   });
});
```

***db.js***

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const eventEmitter = require('events');

global.connectedEmitter = new eventEmitter()

global.sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASS, {
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      port: 1433,
      dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
      ssl: false,
      dialectOptions: {
        ssl:false
      },
      logging:false,
      pool: {
            max: 20,
            min: 0,
            idle: 30000
      }
  });
  sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
  console.log(`${process.env.DB_NAME} - Connection has been established successfully.`);
  global.connectedEmitter.emit('connectedDbs')
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error(' - Unable to connect to the database:', err);
});
```

***.env***  (I am giving dummy credentials as I cannot provide original credentials)

```
# ################################## Database Credentials ##############################################

DB_NAME=mydb
DB_USER=username
DB_PASS=password
DB_HOST=hostname
DB_DIALECT=mssql
```

Can anyone please tell me why am I getting the error mentioned. Where have I made the mistake in setting the database connection. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this issue. Turns out tedious had issues with node versions below 12, and my production app service was running on node 10.

[GitHub link that mentions this](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/issues/1305)